# Grails databinding multiple domain classes

Tags: grails, data-binding

HI. I have this classes:

```
class Carro {

    String name
    String marca
    String matricula

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false, blank:false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }
}
```

---

```
class CarroMovel {
    String move
    String rodas
    String espelhos
    Carro carro

    static hasMany = [carros: Carro]

    static constraints = {
        move(nullable:false, blank:false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }
}
```

And the controllers:

```
class CarroController{
def save2 = {

        def carroInstance = new Carro()
        carroInstance.name = params.name
        carroInstance.marca = params.marca
        carroInstance.matricula = params.matricula

        if (carroInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            redirect(uri:"/home.gsp")
        }
        else {
            render(view: "/testeAdd", model: [carroInstance: carroInstance])
        }

    }
```

And the view testeAdd.gsp

```
<g:form controller="carro" action="save2">
<h1>Add New Carro Record</h1>
<p>Basic Information</p>

<label>Name
<span class="small">as</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="${carroInstance?.name}" /><br>

<label>Marca
<span class="small">as</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="marca" value="${carroInstance?.marca}" /><br

  <label>Matricula
<span class="small">as</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="matricula" value="${carroInstance?.matricula}" /><br>


<g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" id="oneone"/>


<div class="spacer"></div>
  </g:form>

                <g:hasErrors bean="${carroInstance}">
            <div class="errors">
                <g:renderErrors bean="${carroInstance}" as="list" />
            </div>
            </g:hasErrors>
```

This is working good. Now i would like to be able to data binding multiple domain classes. So, along with the current code from my gsp file, i would also like to add carroMovel occurrences all in same save2. Im not sure how to do that, specially cause class Carro will need to have an id from class carroMovel. Any help please? Thank you.

I folowed some suggestions and now the results are as follows (im not concerned about error validation yet):

```
 def save3 = {

        def carroInstance = new Carro()
        def carroMovelInstance = new CarroMovel()

        carroInstance.name = params.carro.name
        carroInstance.marca = params.carro.marca
        carroInstance.matricula = params.carro.matricula

        carroMovelInstance.move = params.carroMovel.move
        carroMovelInstance.rodas = params.carroMovel.rodas
        carroMovelInstance.espelhos = params.carroMovel.espelhos

        carroInstance.save()
        carroMovelInstance.carro = carroInstance
        carroMovelInstance.save()

    }
```

---

```
<g:form controller="carro" action="save3">
<h1>Add New Conference Record</h1>
<p>Basic Information</p>

<label>Name
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="carro.name" value="${carroInstance?.name}" /><br>

<label>Marca
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="carro.marca" value="${carroInstance?.marca}" /><br

  <label>Matricula
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="carro.matricula" value="${carroInstance?.matricula}" /><br>

<label>Move
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="carroMovel.move" value="${carroMovelInstance?.move}" /><br>

<label>Rodas
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="carroMovel.rodas" value="${carroMovelInstance?.rodas}" /><br>

<label>Espelho
<span class="small">Add your name</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="carroMovel.espelho" value="${carroMovelInstance?.espelho}" /><br>

<g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" id="addConference"/>
```

The Carro object is saved in the database, altought, nothing happens with CarroMovel and it is not saved and i can't figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails multiple databinding domain classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048654/grails-multiple-databinding-domain-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can give this a try.
First, edit our form to include the necessary fields for the CarroMovel class,
e.g

```
<label>Move
<span class="small">as</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="move" value="${carroMovelInstance?.move}" />
```

then

in your save2 action,

```
def carroInstance = new Carro()
carroInstance.name = params.name
carroInstance.marca = params.marca
carroInstance.matricula = params.matricula

def carroMovelInstance = new CarroMovel()
carroMovelInstance.name = params.move
carroMovelInstance.marca = params.rodasa
carroMovelInstance.matricula = params.espelhos
carroMovelInstance.carro = carroInstance
```

Since Carro does not belong to CarroMovel saving a carroMovelInstance will not cascade to the carroInstance, therefore you will need to save each instance individually before saving its owning instance.

```
carroMovelInstance.carro.save()
if (carroMovelInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        redirect(uri:"/home.gsp")
    }
    else {
        render(view: "/testeAdd", model: [carroInstance: carroInstance, carroMovelInstance:carroMovelInstance])
  }
```

Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: didnt work. Carro is saved but carroMovel isnt. I dont know why ?!?

Answer (score 2):

First I would change the input names to carro.name, carro.marca, carroMovel.move, ... so that they are differentiated by name.

```
<input type="text" name="carro.name"/><br>
<input type="text" name="carro.marca"/><br>
<input type="text" name="carroMovel.move"/><br>
```

This has the advantage that the binding in the controller can be done the standard Grails way, and that the correct values are entered in the form without the value attribute set.

```
carro.properties = params.carro 
carroMovel.properties = params.carroMovel
```

In the controller action you can also save and link the Carro and CarroMovel instances.

```
carro.save()
carroMovel.carro = carro
carroMovel.save()
if(carroMovel.hasErrors(){
  render(view: 'save3', model: [carro: carro, carroMovel.carroMovel])
}
```

Comment: hello. thanks for the answer. i updated my progress but carroMovel is not saving i dont know why. Please take a look

Comment: Make sure that carroMovel is saved without errors. I edited my post for that.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a command object for this type of thing.

In your controller do something like this:

```
class CarroController {

  def show = {
    [cmd: new MyCommand()]
  }

  def save2 = { MyCommand cmd ->
    def carro = cmd.carro

    if (carro.save()) {
      cmd.movel.carro = carro
      if (cmd.movel.save()) {
        redirect uri: 'home.gsp'
      } else {
        // show form again
        render view: 'show', model:[cmd:cmd]
      }
    } else {
      // show form again
      render view: 'show', model:[cmd:cmd]
    }
  }

  // same file or some other class file
  class MyCommand {
      Carro carro
      CarroMovel movel
  }
}
```

You will need to adjust your form a bit as well...

Where you have "Carro" fields reference them like this:

```
<input type="text" name="carro.matricula" value="${cmd.carro?.matricula}" />
```

Where you have the "CarroMovel" fields, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="movel.rodas" value="${cmd.movel?.rodas}" />
```

This code might not be exactly right (I didn't test it), but should get you down the correct path.  Also instead of referencing the objects in the command object, you could just have the fields that you are binding, and then build the actual domain objects from them, either through a helper method (`def buildCarro(){...}`) or by hand in the controller method.

Comment: you could also adjust your model in this instance to add the movel to the the carro object.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers may be simpler, but I've been using this technique:
http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/

Answer (score 0):

In order for Carro to cascade save the CarroMovel reference, CarroMovel needs  `belongsTo = Carro` or you need to manually tell hibernate to cascade it upon save using something like this:

```
class CarroMovel{
  static mapping = { 
   carro cascade: 'all' 
  }
}
```

Here's the hibernate documentation about cascading: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html