# Grails multiple databinding domain classes

Tags: data-binding, grails, dns

```
  Class Carro {
    String name
    String marca
    String matricula

    } 

    Class CarroMovel{

    String pro1
    String prop2
    String prop3

    Carro carro

    static hasMany = [ carros: Carro]

    }
```

---

```
 def save2 = {

                def carroInstance = new Carro()
                def carroMovelInstance = new CarroMovel()

                carroInstance.name = params.name
                carroInstance.marca = params.marca
                carroInstance.matricula = params.matricula

                carroMovelInstance.prop1 = params.carroMovel.prop1
                carroMovelInstance.prop2 = params.carroMovel.prop2
                carroMovelInstance.prop3 = params.carroMovel.prop3

                carroInstance.save()
                carroMovelInstance.carro = carroInstance
                carroMovelInstance.save()                 

            }
```

The CarroInstance is saving, but the carroMovelInstance isn't. I cannot figure it out. Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a validation error.  Try calling `validate()` on it and inspecting the errors.  Alternatively, try saving it with `carroMovelInstance.save(failOnError: true)` and you'll get an exception if it doesn't validate.

Comment: worked. i solved the problem. there was a bad name in the view. thanks